# How do I prevent redeclaration errors when using Mock classes that implement the IteratorAggregate interface when testing with PHPUnit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I'm writing a unit test that relies on an external class, exceptionManager. I want to be able to predict what some specific functions on this class will return, so I'm using a mock object. The code is quite straightforward:

```
$mockExceptionManager = $this->getMock('exceptionManager');
```

The trouble is, my exception manager implements the IteratorAggregate interface, which requires a method that looks like this:

```
public function getIterator()
{
  return new ArrayIterator($this->exceptions);
}
```

When I run the unit test, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Mock_exceptionManager_ae79bad2::getIterator() in /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.2/lib/php/PEAR/PHPUnit/Framework/MockObject/Generator.php(170) : eval()'d code on line 297

I have a feeling that the PHPUnit mock object suite also implements the IteratorAggregate interface, and the two are clashing, although I'm unsure. I also tried using the Iterator interface, but ran into the same issue. How can I get around this?

Comment: Try passing the second parameter of getMock.  It should be an array of strings with the names of the functions you actually want to mock.  If you purposefully leave out getIterator it may provide a quick work around.

Comment: Feel free to post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I disabled autoloading on the mock object which solved the issue.

```
$mockExceptionManager = $this->getMockBuilder('exceptionManager')
                             ->disableAutoload()
                             ->getMock();
```